# Show pseudo element between elements

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element

I've been trying to work out how to show an `::after` pseudo element *between* each element in a set.

HTML:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="element">Hello</div>
    <div class="element">World</div>
    <div class="element">!</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer .element:not(.outer > .element:last-child)::after
{
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    background:url(images/test.png);
    width:4px;
    height:5px;
}
```

My understanding is that my CSS is targeting all elements with a class of `element` under an element with a class of `outer` that aren't the `:last-child` in that set.  I guess I'm either wrong, or what I'm trying isn't possible?

Is this possible, and if so, how?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just use this:

```
outer .element + .element:before
{
    content:"";
    display:inline-block;
    background:url(images/test.png);
    width:4px;
    height:5px;
}
```

It's the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) syntax.

Edit: swapped after for before pseudo class

Edit 2: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/W5BMy/)

Comment: How does that not target the `:last-child)`?

Comment: @DavidThomas The idea is to target all but the first child and situate the styled object to the left rather than the right.

Comment: And now you've actually used `::before` that makes sense.

Comment: @DavidThomas Yeah.  Sorry about that.  I usually use this method along with absolute positioning so I sometimes forget that before and after make a huge difference. XD

Comment: @JosephMarikle Many thanks! I'm not really a CSS guy, but I've been trying to brush up, this worked a charm!

Comment: +1 for simple logic. I guess this is a good example of "Keep it simple, stupid". (With no offense intended to the OP :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can write your selector a much simplier way : **[DEMO](http://fiddle.jshell.net/W6krK/)**

`.outer .element + .element:before {/* your CSS rules */}`

Instead , your target every element from second, and use the `:before` pseudo. this will work much better and will increase compatibility.